# fopen not displaying contents

Tags: php

Not sure why my im getting a blank page ? There is data in the .txt and no errors in the php ?

```
<?php
$fp = fopen("products.txt", "r");
flock($fp, LOCK_SH);
$headings = fgetcsv($fp, 0, "\t");
while ($aLineOfCells = fgetcsv($fp, 0, "\t")) {
$records[] = $aLineOfCells;
}
flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
fclose($fp);
echo $aLineOfCells;
?>
```

This is the .txt

```
Product.txt
ID  OID Title   Description Option  Price
01  01JAP   Japanese Model  This is the japanese option Japanese    $3000   
02  02ENG   English Model   This is the english option  English $3000
```

Comment: You're echoing the last value of the read lines, which is supposed to be nothing, otherwise the while loop would continue infinitely. Also, this has nothing to do with JavaScript or HTML.

Comment: You should have to print `print_r($records)`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you are echo the last line.

And every $aLineOfCells is an array.You need to take it out.

```
<?php
$fp = fopen("products.txt", "r");
flock($fp, LOCK_SH);
$headings = fgetcsv($fp, 0, "\t");

$aline = '';
while ($aLineOfCells = fgetcsv($fp, 0, "\t")) {
  $records[] = $aLineOfCells[0];
  $aline = $aline . $aLineOfCells[0] . "\n";
}

flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
fclose($fp);
echo $aline;
?>
```